# Merge and calculate excel rows to new sheet based on unique number

Tags: excel-formula

I have a large excel sheet that contains duplicates unique numbers, but the information behind each unique number differs. The original sheets needs to be partially copied to a new sheet. The new (master) sheet needs to contain the same unique number, but calculates the total order and tax value. Please see a simplified example below.

> **Sheet 1**
>   Unique number   Product value   Tax
>   1   a    $5.00   $1.00 
>   2   b    $4.00   $0.75 
>   2   a    $7.50   $1.50 
>   3   e    $3.00   $0.50
>
> To **sheet 2**
>   Unique number   value   Tax
>   1    $5.00   $1.00 
>   2    $11.00      $2.25 
>   3    $3.00   $0.50

Any guidance is much appreciated

Comment: Are these values merged? I mean is "1 a $5.00 $1.00 " in one cell? If so first use text to columns to seperate them. Than you can use "SUMIF" function or Pivot Table.

Comment: Are the unique numbers sorted?  Are the Uniques numbers truly numbers or are the serial number that may contain some letters in  them?

Answer (score 0):

I did it with the use of a helper column.

So the first thing I did was to generate a list of unique number.  I did it with a formula, but there is also a function built into Excel that will do this.  The following formula generate a list of unique numbers and places a blank where values are duplicated.

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$1:A1,A1)=1,A1,"")
```

I placed that in the first column of your new table.  In the second column of your new table I sorted the list and removed the blank using this formula:

```
=IFERROR(SMALL($G$1:$G$4,ROW()-ROW($A$1)+1),"")
```

Then as per ctumturks comment I used sumif as follows:

```
=IF($H1="","",SUMIF($A$1:$A$4,$H1,C$1:C$4))
```

That last formula can be copied to the right to sum each subsequent column.

to use the built in function for removing duplicates, select all the unique numbers.  Copy and paste them to your new sheet.  In your new sheet select the unique numbers again.  Go to your Data ribbon at the top.  About half way across there is a tool called "Remove duplicates".  This will remove duplicate numbers in place and remove spaces at the same time.  After you have completed this you should only need the last formula above in the adjacent column.